# Optimizing cartesian product using keys in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

To avoid computing all possible combinations, I'm trying to group values according to a certain key, and then compute the cartesian product of the values for each key, i.e.:

```
Input [(k1, v1), (k1, v2), (k2, v3)]
```

Desired output: `[(v1, v1), (v1, v2), (v2, v2), (v2, v1), (v3, v3)]` Here is code I have tried executing:

```
val input = sc.textFile('data.csv')
val rdd = input.map(s=>s.split(","))
               .map(s => (s(1).toString,  s(2).toString))
val group_result:RDD[String, Iterable[String]] = rdd.groupByKey()
group_result.flatMap { t =>
{
  val stream1= t._2.toStream
  val stream2= t._2.toStream

  stream1.flatMap { src =>
    stream2.par.map { trg =>
            src + "," + trg
    }
  }
}
}
```

This works fine for very small files, but when the list(Iterable) is of length ~1000 the computation completely freezes.

Comment: You shouldn't mix RDD maps (transformations in general) with Scala native ones. Inner ones aren't optimized by Spark; maybe this is the reason it freezes.

Comment: @TomaszBłachut Whaaaat? Why wouldn't you? :) `groupByKey` is probably not the best idea here, `toStream` offers no benefits, and simple self `join` would be enough but there is nothing particularly wrong with using "Scala  map".

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for clarification, I think I should start prefixing my comments with AFAIR :> That exists in my head as something not to do, maybe I've seen different examples that looked bad

Answer (score 0):

As @zero323 said, the best way to solve this is by using PairRDDFunctions' method [join](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@join[W](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W)],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(V,W))]), however in order to achieve this you need to have a `PairedRDD`, which can be obtained by using RDD's method [keyBy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@keyBy[K](f:T=%3EK):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,T)]).

You could do something like:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("k1", "v1"), ("k1", "v2"), ("k2", "v3"))).keyBy(_._1)

val result = rdd.join(rdd).map{
  case (key: String, (x: Tuple2[String, String], y: Tuple2[String, String])) => (x._2, y._2)
}

result.take(20)
// res9: Array[(String, String)] = Array((v1,v1), (v1,v2), (v2,v1), (v2,v2), (v3, v3))
```

[Here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/379936671845911/8589256059752547/latest.html) I share the notebook with the code.